# ¿Por que el modal no respeta el diseño?

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Este modal siempre me da problemas y me hace retomar el proyecto desde donde lo deje antes, porque algo me causa conflicto a la hora de mostrarlo, utilizo bootstrap 4 pero por motivos de compatibilidad tengo los archivos de la version 3 en el mismo proyecto, los cuales se usan en otros archivos diferentes al modal que me da problemas. Podría ser esta la causa del problema? tener la libreria anterior, ya que mi index carga 4 archivos en un collapse cada uno, con un include y algunos de los archivos a los que estos que estos hacen referencia tienen a su vez algunos link y script de la libreria vieja precargada.

Codigo del modal:

```
    <div id="modalrdsubdir" class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg " role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header text-center" >
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Reenvio de Director a Subdirector</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="envia_rd_subdir.php">
                <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <label for="foliordsubdir">Folio</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="foliordsubdir" id="foliordsubdir" placeholder="Folio">
                                </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                        <label for="temasolrdsubdir">Tema de solicitud</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="temasolrdsubdir" id="temasolrdsubdir" placeholder="Tema de solicitud">
                                </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                            <label for="fechardsubdir">Fecha de solicitud</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fechardsubdir" id="fechardsubdir" placeholder="Fecha de Solicitud">
                                </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Enviar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Me habia funcionado bien con anterioridad, pero con tan solo comentar y descomentar alguna linea de las librerias donde incluyo el bootstrap se echa a perder, aun no logro encontrar la verdadera causa y esto me esta reteniendo de avanzar.

[image: Asi es como se muestra actualmente, ya se mostraba bien antes, es una cosa rara la que derrepente hace que no se muestre como se debeintroducir el código aquí]

Comment: Sólo con leer que tienes en el mismo proyecto dos versiones de Bootstrap diferentes me da para pensar que ese es el error. Lo mejor es que uses la última versión, en este caso v4. Puedes revisar la migración para que te ayude con el cambio: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/migration/

Comment: Si, es eso, pero por alguna razón, si funcionaba a veces, ya que había tenido 2 versiones diferentes sin problemas pero luego de la nada dejaba de funcionar, supongo que omití alguna llamada a la librería en otro archivo y eso causaba conflicto.